# Running Node and React concurrently

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, concurrency, mern

I am making a MERN app and having some problems with connecting/running node and react server together.

Root package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "populatedb": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.8"
  }
}
```

Client proxy:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
"secure": false
```

Main server file:

```
require('dotenv').config();

var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// set up mongoose connection
const mongoDB = process.env.DB_STRING;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:' ));
console.log('Connected');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

//Express js listen method to run project on http://localhost:5000
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`App is running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`))

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I am using 'npm run dev' command to start the server.
I am getting an error message "proxy error: could not proxy request /users from localhost:3000 to [http://127.0.0.1:5000"](http://127.0.0.1:5000%22).
I have tried changing proxy to 0.0.0 and also changed the scripts file to:

```
"start": "node ./bin/www",
"devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\""
```

but it still does not work. I have tried some other solutions I've found but just can't get it right.

Here is also my test react file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("/users");
    setUsers(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((u) => (
        <h4 key={u._id}>userName : {u.full_name}</h4>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is also my folder structure, if it is relevant by any chance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying some more solutions to fix the problem, what worked is:
in one terminal tab run `nodemon app.js`
in second terminal tab run `npm start --prefix client`.

There is probably something wrong with concurrently module, since this is working.